# What is the method to mute sound during seek on RDA5807 FM?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation

How to does noise canceling work on this[RDA5807M](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/RDA5807M_C82537.pdf) FM radio module?
What can I do to mute noise on the radio?
I want to mute immediately when there is blank white noise on the FM radio.

Comment: How are you controlling it?

Comment: I control it with Arduino

Comment: That answers "with what", not "how". How do you control it with Arduino? If you have source code then post it. Are you sure the radio chip has no auto mute based on RSSI?

Comment: -1I Welcome. The downvote for your question is because this information is easily found by reading the datasheet and researching the information found there. I did provide an answer. I do not want to discourage you from seeking help here, Please don't ask us to read the datasheet for you. I am more than willing to help you understand the datasheet information if you have made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick scan of the data sheet and found

1. A digital mute register.
2. An RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication) register.

These are accessible through I2C.

White noise occurs at low RSSI.

Pseudo code:

```
Read RSSI
Compare to desired threshold
If too low than mute else unmute
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious, but there must be an automatic setting.

My guess is to **set 10 for Seek mode.**

[image]

There is no description of how SNR is detected but it is probably not calibrated in dB exactly but the binary "1000" must be a value that can be read on the RSSI byte or Received Signal Strength Indicator common to most radios and WiFi modems.

[image]

I hope it mutes after a seek failure after one loop scan.

But we can see there is a 7-bit value for RSSI. This might cover a 60 dB dynamic range is my guess and the example threshold is just more than 3 bits 1000 of the resolution, but you can change that depending on your local power supply or line noise. If it seeks to some harmonic noise, then find out if you can reduce the source noise by a better (longer) antenna or else, raise the **4 bit SEEKTH** value.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot can you write me the arduino code i want to test it

Comment: Ok you send a beer and Andy will write it

Comment: Arduino code:
https://pastebin.com/UC1zmkUR

Library code:

keywords.txt
https://pastebin.com/SE3uSiDP

RDA5807M.cpp
https://pastebin.com/akqCEgkn

RDA5807M.h
https://pastebin.com/Tf0bKygi

Comment: Just kidding. I answered your question now get to work

Comment: I tried for a long time but somehow I couldn't succeed in blocking the noises there is no video about it about how to block the noise

Comment: `I tried for a long time` ... how long is that? ... @TonyStewartEE75 answered you 2 hours ago ... you asked for code one hour after that ... that does not leave much time for writing test code ... even less time if you continue to search for videos ... `there is no video`

Answer (score -1):

[image: RDA5807 Arduino Code]

RDA5707M.cpp noisReduction code(library)

```
void RDA5807M::noisReduction(uint16_t Reduction) { //SOFTBLEND_EN
  Reduction = constrain(Reduction, 0, 31);
  uint16_t Reg07h = getRegister(RDA5807M_REG_NOISE); // Считываем текущее значение
  if (Reduction)
  {
    Reg07h |= 1 << RDA5807M_BIT_NOIS;
    Reg07h &= ~RDA5807M_NOIS_MASK; // Сбрасываем биты NOIS
    Reg07h |= Reduction << RDA5807M_BIT_NOIS_DATA_SHIFT; // Устанавливаем уровень шумодава
  }
  else
  {
    Reg07h &= ~(1 << RDA5807M_BIT_NOIS);
  }
  setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_NOISE, Reg07h);
}
```

[image: An image from my project]

RDA5807 Radio and Pam Amplifier circuit

Comment: Coder1448 - Hi, This answer isn't clear to me either. Either (a) You are writing it as an *answer*, because it's the final answer to your question. If so, please "accept" an answer, yours or another one (green "tick") to close the whole question. Or (b) You are mistakenly writing this as an *answer*, when in fact you still want replies / help. In that case, this is an *update*, not an answer, and must be "edited into" your original question i.e. click "Edit" under the question, add this update, state what help is still needed, then delete this "answer". Which applies here, (a) or (b)? Thanks

Comment: To help avoid problems, please read the [tour] and the [help]. You posted another "answer" containing that photo of your project, so I'm concerned that you are treating this site like a typical "linear forum" (where everything gets posted in the same thread), instead of how things are done on Stack Exchange with a question (that gets clarified, as needed), answers (that should at least partially answer the original question), and [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756). I see you have not yet read the [tour] so please do that now, as a minimum. Thanks.